# Apply style to multiple html elements of the same class with css or sass

Tags: css, sass

I want to apply a style to all `<p>` and `<input>` elements of the `numeric` class using css.

Is it possible to consolidate this so that I only write "numeric" once?

```
p.numeric,input.numeric {
    float: right;
}
```

I'm also using sass, so if it's not possible in CSS is it possible with the sass additions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

yes it is possible:

```
p, input {
    &.numeric {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

The '&' is necceassry to connect with p/input. Without the result will be `p .numeric {...}`

Comment: I don't think the & is necessary. Is there an issue with just nesting as @hunter suggested?

Comment: yea, added some clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do .numeric, but then it would apply to everything with a class of numeric.  If you only want it to apply to paragraphs and inputs then what you're doing is the correct approach.